# Conditional Expectation and covariance

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation, conditional-expectation

Assume that the random vector $(X,Y)$ is (bivariate) normally distributed. Show that
$ \Bbb E[X|Y=y]= \Bbb E[X]+ \frac {Cov[X,Y]}{Var[Y]}(y-\Bbb E[Y])$

Also, 
$ Var[X|Y=y]= (1-\rho^2) Var[X]$

I know i should be converting these variables into standard normal and then using Cholesky decomposition to come up with independent standard normal, I am getting pretty close to the answer but, its not neat. I might have done something wrong, Can some one please lay out the first step to convert X&Y to standard normal?? Thanks so much